# What's a word for short bursts of speech?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Something happened. Your brother comes running to you and starts talking in breathless .........?

I'm looking for a word like bursts, but bursts of speech.

Comment: Amin, Please use the title to direct people to the sort of thing you're asking about, and put the detail in the body of the question. Also, **please show your own research:** have you used a [reverse dictionary](https://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml), for example? Or a thesaurus — you could start by looking up words related to "breathless," like *gasp.*

Comment: Thank you <3. I'll put this mind for my next questions.

Comment: @Amin You don't need to wait for the next question, you can edit this question now to make it better.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities; they can be sampled from this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22speaking%20in%20breathless%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

- gasps, bursts, tones, whispers, ellipses

You can add "*staccato*".

> (SOED) **B.** *n.* staccato delivery, playing, or speech.

Comment: also [***spluttering***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/splutter) - *(of a person) to produce short, unclear noises from your mouth, **especially because you cannot breathe properly***.